# Получение данных по сети в разработке под Android

Tags: java, android, rest, node.js

Всем доброго утра! Проблема заключается в выборе способа: мне требуется забирать некоторый JSON, который отдается на API сервера (Node.js по некоторому запросу вернет JSON по SQL-запросу к бд). Наверное, это всё, что требуется.

Во-первых, достаточно ли, чтобы сервер только принимал запрос и в ответ возвращал информацию по запросу? Как это с точки зрения безопасности?

И каким образом на андроиде отправляют такой запрос и как дождаться ответа в виде того что мне требуется?

Comment: Есть библиотеки Retrofit и аналогичные, которые существенно облегчат общение приложения с сетью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно или нет - зависит от того, что сервис отдаёт. Если это публичные данные, нет смысла их закрывать. Если приватные, можно использовать секретный ключ, как это делает большинство web-сервисов.

Отправляется теми же способами, как и в любой другой java-программе. И как и в любой другой java-программе (исключая, может быть, консольные утилиты) стоит делать это в фоновом потоке. В Android для этого есть [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) и [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Выбор одного из них зависит от особенностей вашей программы. Пример использования AsyncTask:

```
private class GetJsonTask extends AsyncTask<URL, String, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) { //Фоновый поток
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)urls[0].openConnection();
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.close();
            return new JSONObject(out.toString());
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { //Callback в главном потоке
        //Делайте с вашим json всё, что нужно.
    }
}

new GetJsonTask().execute(new URL('http://myservice.ru/somedata.json'));
```

Comment: Начиная с Android 3.0 вы и никак  не сможете работать с сетью в основном потоке, вместо этого получите NetworkOnMainThreadExeption. Так что особо выбирать не приходится :) Можно было бы упомянуть о либах, вроде Retrofit. Работать с сетью в реальном приложении через собственные классы, когда есть Retrofit как то .. олдскульно

Comment: Я свято верю, что новичку надо сначала разобраться с базовыми функциями, а уж потом начинать облегчать себе жизнь.

Comment: Базовые функции приходят из Java: java.net.Socket, java.lang.Thread.

Comment: @tse и их тоже неплохо было бы знать.

Comment: Всегда есть баланс между закопаться в теории и писать работающие приложения. Андроид настолько сложен, что в некоторых случаях приходится выполнять какие-то действия как ритуалы, и только со временем вникать в их суть.